# Placeholder in date_field_tag rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-4, input-field

I am trying to use placeholder in date_field_tag using rails 4. But instead of showing placeholder value it keeps showing 'dd-mm-yyyy'

My code

```
<%= date_field_tag "event_date", "", class: "form-control input-md", placeholder: "Event Date *", required: true %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can use in html format like this
In Html
<input placeholder="Event Date *" class="textbox-n" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')"  id="date"> 

In Haml
%input#date.textbox-n{:onfocus => "(this.type='date')", :placeholder => "Event Date *", :type => "text"}/
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work. Is there any way that we can hide the date increment thing and have only calendar thing.